# changing the project and target name in XCode

Tags: objective-c, project, xcode4.6, targets

I created a project and I fully developed it.

I need to change the name of the project and targets. is there an easy way to do that or should I just create a new project and copy all the items in there?

Thanks

Comment: Xcode doesn't have a captial C, it's Xcode, not XCode

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can change the project name by clicking on the project name at the top of the left sidebar and then entering a new name under the Identity on the right sidebar and finally pressing Return.

Comment: Changing the target name is just as simple. Click on the project name at the top left, then select a target name on the right pane followed by pressing "Enter". Type in the new name.

Comment: Note that in Xcode 5, the center editor pane's menu bar (where you see General, Capabilities, Info, etc) has a little "play" triangle icon that shows/hides the Projects and Targets List pane.  You have to click that to open it, then you can long-click an item to change its name.

Comment: Something else worth mentioning is that after doing this I had to recreate the schemes (Edit Schemes->Autocreate Schemes Now)

Comment: @Alan, in Xcode 6, this was changed to a square icon, with a bolded line on the left side.

Comment: I was switching between Windows and OSX a lot and I accidentally pressed ALT-Tab in the target name for my app and Xcode made the target name blank.  It wouldn't let me rename it after that. Very frustrating.

Comment: Something else to mention : go to your (project-name)-info.plist file and Change the "Bundle Display Name" value to the new project name